# Transaction in function sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server, function, transactions

I have question. That I can use transaction in function in SQL Server 2012? Because now I have error:

```
Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'BEGIN TRANSACTION' within a function.
```

Comment: Can you tell us why you think it makes sense to use begin transaction in a function?

Comment: Because I must make transaction in function to school. I can choose the enviroment (oracle, ms sql, itd). I know that should be in stored procedure but, it is avaible to make it in fuction?

Comment: Transactions cannot be used in a function in SQL Server, and I would be surprised if they could be used in a function in any other database. Are you sure you were asked to do it in a function, and not in a stored procedure?

Comment: No, in stored prcedure I do it already. Okey, Thanks for help. Problem solved ;)

Comment: @marcin_poland Dear Marcin, reading documentation is critical at some point. Learning SQL in school I am ashamed that you have not ever considered actually learning your topic. Transactions are not avaialble in functions in any sql variant / server that I know of due to the limitation of what a function IS. If your teacher demanded that - he is someone who should be fired (send him here to read that). But more likely you mix things up.

Comment: I know how use function, but I don`t why and how I can make transaction in fuction. I write there to how 100% certainty. Mayby this was sneaky order. One more time, thanks for help ;)

Answer (score 0):

if you are writing the function to better structure a script, you can call it "procedure" instead of "function", and pass it one or more OUTPUT parameters to receive the computed result.

a "function" cannot have side effects, like inserting/updating/deleting rows or creating/altering/dropping of structures.

i had the same problem and [found the solution at the sqlservertutorial](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-stored-procedures/stored-procedure-output-parameters/) , and i heartly recommend you that reading.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE uspFindProductByModel (
    @model_year SMALLINT,
    @product_count INT OUTPUT
) AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        product_name,
        list_price
    FROM
        production.products
    WHERE
        model_year = @model_year;

    SELECT @product_count = @@ROWCOUNT;
END;
```

to invoke the procedure and receive the result:

```
DECLARE @count INT;

EXEC uspFindProductByModel
    @model_year = 2018,
    @product_count = @count OUTPUT;
```

i have to mention, that the procedure in this example does not have any side effects, as changing data in the db, so that it could be built as a function as well.
anyway, a procedure seems more versatile, and may support many output parameters, instead of only one return value.
yes i know, a function may return an aggregate.

good luck,